Is it possible to convert a UIImage into a Microsoft.Maui.Image?
I've been unable to figure out how so far. I've tried searching for documents, tutorials and the MAUI source code but haven't yet figured this out. It seemed so much easier to do in Xamarin Forms, from recollection. Can somebody tell me what I'm missing here? The Android approach would also be a bonus (i.e. Android.Media.Image or Bitmap?).

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to convert the iOS native UIImage to the Microsoft.Maui.Image of the share platform?

Yes, exactly. Can it be done?

My original thought was like Riccardo Minato said, have you solved the problem now?

You can do that passing through a Stream.
Assuming uiImage is your iOS image and bitmap is your Android image:
Stream? stream = null;

#if IOS
stream = uiImage.AsPNG()?.AsStream();
#elif ANDROID
stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
#endif

if (stream is not null)
    Image image = new Image
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream)
    };

I didn't test it so something could fail. Think of it as a starting point.

I tried this approach earlier, and it didn't preserve the height or width of the UIImage. I can make a height and width request, but I don't think these set anything unless the view is placed on screen?

A few questions: what's the resulting image size, respect to the original? What do you expect it to be? Why you need an Image if you don't have to show it on the screen?

The size goes from 1080 x 1920 to -1 x -1. I will show it on the screen eventually. What I'm mainly trying to do is convert a large amount of UIImage code and Android Image code into a cross-platform class that works on both types.

The original image resolution is different from MAUI Image size property. The latter depends on how you show the image on the screen. If you want to show the original resolution, get it from the platform specific image before converting it to a Stream.

Okay that might be fine. I need that original width and height for cropping purposes. I’ll give this a try and see what my crop looks like. Thanks for the help!
